# iPhone plays/pauses/skips songs and activates siri only when connected to earphones

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, headphones, siri

I have had my iphone 5s (still have version 7.1.1) for three years now and never have encountered such a problem until recently.

When I plug my earphones, it works well depending on whether i want to facetime or play music but lately, it frequently stops, skips, pauses songs or activate Siri on its own accord. It even ends my facetime calls while i'm talking, so i have to call back every time (I can call back for more than 7-10 times).

Can someone help me???

PS: it never does this when its not connected to my headphones

Answer (score 3):

**You need a new headset.**

The symptoms you are describing is because the "controller" assembly of your headset (the part that has the buttons and the microphone) is failing; most likely due to moisture (or some other contaminant) getting in and interfering with the circuitry.

[image: Apple Ear Buds with controller]

I have had this happen to me on several occasions and not just limited to Apple headsets.    Get a good quality headset that is also water resistant like the [Bose SoundSport](http://radnex.us/bose_soundsport_apple) and you shouldn't have this problem again.  (Going on 4 years with my Bose where I wouldn't last a year with the regular ones).

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the headphone jack plug. If you put an adaptor (3.5mm female to 3.5mm male) in between the headphones and iPhone/ iPod, it'll solve the problem. I found a 100mm adaptor on eBay for £2. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as lint build-up in the headphone jack, I had the same problem. Gently clean out the inside of the jack with a paper clip or similar item (I used lead from a mechanical pencil because I was at school). I pulled out two clumps of lint and the problem stopped. Don't worry about damaging the jack. As long as you don't jam something in there or get anything stuck you won't hurt it. Good luck.